# React/Redux : State Updated but component not refreshing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, components, state

I am building an app with React/Redux.

Here is the Json:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "category 1",
      "slug": "category-1"
      "content": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "title 1 "
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "title 2 "
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to do, is to add a content for a category.

- the path "/categories" = list of categories
- I click on category, I am redirected to the "/categories/id" = list
  of content for this category.

I am trying to add a content.
when I add a content ("title") my state is updated but my component does not.

here is my app.js

```
const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <div className="container">         
            <Navbar/>           
            <hr/>
            <Route exact path="/(categories|)/" component={CategoryList} />
                <Route exact path="/categories/:id" component={CategoryDetail} />
        </div>
    </Router>
);
```

the CategoryDetail component

```
    class CategoryDetail extends Component {

        getDetail() {
            console.log("getdetail here");      
            const detail = this.props.categorySelected.content.map((content) =>
                <div key={content._id}> 
                    <p> <strong>{content.title}</strong></p>
                </div>
            );

            return (
                <div>
                    {detail}
                </div>
            );      
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div>
                        {this.getDetail()}
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <CategoryAddContent/>   
                </div>          
            );
        }
    }

    function mapStateToProps (state) {
        return {        
            categorySelected: state.categories.categorySelected 
        };  
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CategoryDetail);
```

when I console log "getdetail here" is not printed when I submit a new content. It means that the component is not loaded. But I don't know how to fix this.

then CategoryAddContent component

```
    class CategoryAddContent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {title: "",};
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const contentData = {title: this.state.title};
        this.props.createCategoryContent(this.props.categorySelected, contentData);
        this.setState({title : ""});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Add content</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label>name: </label> <br/>
                        <input
                            type="text" 
                            name="name" 
                            value={this.state.name}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <input 
                        type="submit" 
                        value="Submit" 
                    />
                </form>         
            </div>
        );
    }
}


// reducer
function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        categorySelected: state.categories.categorySelected
    };  
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createCategoryContent })(CategoryAddContent);
```

The action creator of createCategoryContent

```
export const createCategoryContent= (categoryContent, newContent) => dispatch => {
        categoryContent["content"] = [...categoryContent["content"], newContent];
        dispatch ({
            type: NEW_CATEGORY_CONTENT,
            payload: categoryContent
        })
    };
```

Reducer here:

```
case NEW_CATEGORY_CONTENT:
    return {
        ...state,
        categorySelected: action.payload
    };
```

Here we are!

the state is updated but the component is not updated.

Here is the state:

BEFORE

```
categories
- categoryItems {//all categories here}
- categorySelected:id:"XX", name: "XX", slug:"XX", content:[0] // 1 array
```

AFTER

```
categories
- categoryItems {//all categories here}
- categorySelected:id:"XX", name: "XX", slug:"XX", content:[0, 1] // 2 arrays
```

Comment: What’s the “title” in the state? I don’t see the usage

Comment: There's a mutation in `createCategoryContent`. Try removing `categoryContent["content"] = ..` and using `payload: {...categoryContent, content: [...categoryContent.content, newContent]}`

Answer (score 0):

can you think of creating a different function which does the fetch on your action creators. When your categories have been successfully created you can then call the action creator that you have declared in your actions creator file. This can be best used with promises.

Comment: hum .. make sense. you can just tell me more about it, plz

Comment: So say you are making a call from your API. you obviously expect a response. right?? so using promises whatever is under a status code 200 is returned if action is successful. .catch is then returned after the action is unsuccessful and either a 400 or a 500 has been returned by the server or the API.

Now how you call the action creator of creating categories you expect that something be returned from the API and therefore you will use .then() inside the .then() promise its where you will call your action creator for fetching the categories.